# creating slide down menus in a while loop with dynamic data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use php to display a table of data drawn from my mysql database. I have a while loop that loops through each row and spits out the user data.

I want to have a more details button that when pressed will drop down a div box displaying "more details" about the user. The problem I've run into is when I create the div to hold the more details I can't figure out how to make it unique for each user.

When I click the more details link it always opens the top most div only... because my id's aren't  unique. To make the div's unique I could just echo a count to them and the href but I'm not sure how to pass that into jquery as parameter so that when I click the more details link next to a users name it will display the more details div specific to that user.

I've been toying with the below code without much luck, help appreciated. Thanks.

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.moreDetails').click(function() {
            $("#moreDetails").toggle('fast');
        });
    });
    </script>


while()
{

user info...  more details href
<div></div> to display below once more details href has been clicked.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$('a.moreDetails').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('fast');
});
```

This will take the next element after the anchor link (`<a>`) and toggle it.

Then the HTML might look like

```
User 1 (username) <a href="#" class="moreDetails">(details)</a>
<div class="details">More details about User 1</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a bit of trouble at first because I had the href inside a table and when I clicked it the div would not appear. But once i took it out of the table and put it directly above the div it worked. Is there a way to specify the next() to f ind just div elements and not table cells, I'm presuming that's what it was doing.

Comment: You could hop up to the parent div, then get the next TD element and toggle that:

`$(this).parent().next().toggle('fast');`

jQuery gives you all sorts of tools to navigate from one element to another. Take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing for more info.

Answer (score 0):

if your code looks something like the following

```
while()
{

user info...  more details href
<a class="moreDetails" href="">blabla more details</a>
<div></div> to display below once more details href has been clicked.

}
```

then you could toggle the div after the "moreDetails" link like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('a.moreDetails').click(function() {
            $(this).next().toggle('fast');
    });
});
```